# How to test whether a c++ code has compilation error

Tags: c++, testing, compilation

```
/* I have this code in src folder*/ 

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()

    enter code here{
                    cout<< "Hello World";
                    return 0;
                    }

// What should be the test code that checks if the source code has any compilation error ?
```

Comment: Compile the code, and the compiler will tell you.

Comment: Have you tried running your compiler and seeing if it emits any compilation errors? That would be the normal way to tell.

Comment: Test in what programming language? Regardress of that, the basic way is to launch your compiler and check what it outputs or its process exit status from the code.

Comment: As presented, this won't compile. If that helps.

Comment: The question is a bit puzzling because if you remove everything between `main()` and  `{`, then your code will compile. If you put any code there, the compiler will give an error.

Comment: By the way, it would be clearer to separate the code from the context/question.

Comment: @stefaanv Any code? Try `{return 0;} int hoge()`

Comment: I am using a customized build tool(written in python) to build a project written in cpp. As a  part of test cases I want to check if the given source code has any compilation error while building it, if there is any compilation error , the build should fail. So how do I write a test case for my build tool that checks if the given source code in cpp has any compilation errors

Comment: Check the return value from your command line compiler.  Also read through the compiler's documentation to see what values are returned to the operating system.

Comment: You would better separate the duties of the app code and the compiler